# Merge duplicate records and update its table

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me with my problem with SQL Query?

I want to merge/(sum if necessary) all data of the `customer` with duplicate customer mame.

In my project, I already find out all the customer that has been duplicated using this code:

```
select Firstname, Lastname, count(1) as RepeatedCount 
from customer
group by FirstName, LastName
having count(1) > 1
```

How can I update `Customer` table with only 1 customer record and get the sum of `totalsales` and `totavisits` in one record only.

---

Sample data:

```
FirstName  LastName   TotalSales     TotalVisits
---------- ---------- -------------- -----------
Michelle   Go         0.00           0
Michelle   Go         6975.00        1
Michelle   Go         1195.00        1
Michelle   Go         9145.00        3
Michelle   Go         57785.00       5
Michelle   Go         5845.00        1
Michelle   Go         0.00           0
Michelle   Go         0.00           0
```

Expected Output:

```
FirstName  LastName   TotalSales     TolalVisits
---------- ---------- -------------- -----------
Michelle   Go         80945.00       11
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: SQL Server gentleman.

Answer (score 1):

You have use the aggregate function `SUM` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,
SUM(totalsales) as totalsales,
SUM(totalvisits) as totalvisits
FROM customer
GROUP BY FirstName,LastName;
```

And for better practice I suggest you to add a column for `customerId` which is unique.
So that you can group it easily.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b567d/1)

Comment: Yah , Thats want I want the result,
But, How can I delete those duplicate record and this output to customer table ? other says, I need to put it on temp table, but I dont know how.

Comment: In your case each row having different `totalsales` and `totalvisits` values. So how do you want to delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` and insert the results in a temporary table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempTable

SELECT
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    SUM(c.TotalSales) AS TotalSales,
    SUM(c.TotalVisits) AS TolalVisits
INTO #tempTable
FROM Customer c
GROUP BY c.LastName, c.FirstName
```

The, `TRUNCATE` the original table, `Customer`, and `INSERT` the data of `#tempTable`:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Customer
INSERT INTO Customer
    SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```

Comment: You make my smile wider than the equator :) Thanks Felix
All I can to now to is not truncate the entire table, I will select data to delete .
Thanks Again :)

Comment: Why not `TRUNCATE`? The first query will return all unique `customer` and their `totalvists` and `totalsales`.

Comment: Because in my real table, there are some customer without duplicate

Answer (score 0):

**Let us consider below CTE as main table.**

```
;WITH user_details
AS
(
    SELECT 'Michelle' AS FirstName,'Go' AS LastName,0.00 AS totalsales,0 AS totalvists
UNION
    SELECT 'MICHELLE','GO',6975.00,1
UNION
    SELECT 'michelle','go',1195.00,1
UNION
    SELECT 'michelle','go',9145.00,3
UNION
    SELECT 'MICHELLE','GO',57785.00,5
UNION
    SELECT 'MICHELLE','GO',5845.00,1
UNION
    SELECT 'Michelle','Go',0.00,0
UNION
    SELECT 'Michelle','Go',0.00,0
)
```

> Group your query with aggregate function and insert into a temp table

```
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(totalsales)   [totalsales],
    SUM([totalvists]) [totalvisits]
INTO
    #temp
FROM
    user_details
GROUP BY
    FirstName,
    LastName

-- select * from #temp
```

> Truncate your Main table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE user_details
```

> Now again insert the updated records into your new table

```
INSERT INTO user_details (FirstName,LastName,totalsales,totalvisits -- Main table
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    totalsales,
    totalvisits
FROM
    #temp
```